# How to enable the JMX of cluster servers on Weblogic?(not the Weblogic AdminServer itself)

Tags: java, linux, weblogic, jmx, zabbix

I am running Weblogic 12c on CentOS6. I have enabled the JMX on Weblogic AdminServer.
But I want to enable the JMX on the cluster servers such as ms1 listed below to monitor specific Java service. What shall I do? Thank you!

Servers：AdminServer(admin)

Clusters: ms1/ms2/ms3

```
[root@weblogic61 bin]# ps -ef |grep java
weblogic  3618  3571  0 Jun04 ?        03:14:41 /home/jdk/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dweblogic.Name=ms1 -Djava.security.policy=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/cacerts -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/jdk/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/endorsed:/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/endorsed -da -Dplatform.home=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1 -Dwls.home=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server -Dweblogic.home=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server -Dweblogic.management.discover=false -Dweblogic.management.server=http://192.168.97.61:7001 -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath weblogic.Server
root     27588 27541 41 09:56 pts/0    00:00:25 /home/jdk/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/jdk/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/endorsed:/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/endorsed -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.97.61 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder -da -Dplatform.home=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1 -Dwls.home=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server -Dweblogic.home=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath weblogic.Server
root     27638 27312  0 09:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java
zabbix   27853     1  0 Jun13 ?        00:14:16 java -server -classpath lib:lib/logback-classic-0.9.27.jar:lib/logback-core-0.9.27.jar:lib/org-json-2010-12-28.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:bin/zabbix-java-gateway-2.0.12.jar -Dzabbix.pidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_java.pid -Dzabbix.listenIP=0.0.0.0 -Dzabbix.listenPort=10052 -Dzabbix.startPollers=5 com.zabbix.gateway.JavaGateway
```

Comment: well the settings seem to be there, what error are you getting?

Comment: the process 27588(the Weblogic adminserver) have the settings but the process 3618 have not. I want to add those settings to process 3618.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is where are those settings coming from for your admin server. My guess is you need to edit `startWebLogic.sh` and find where the following are being set:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345"
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Thos settings are probably being explicitly set for your admin server only based on an if statement or some such.

You can also set those -D values for your managed server by going to:

```
 Admin Console -> Servers -> MS -> Server Start -> JVM Arguments
```

Last, in the `Weblogic Domain->Configuration->General->Advanced` 
Enable both - `Platform MBean Server Enabled` and `Platform MBean Server Used`

Comment: This really helped, thanks! but I am confused that are the managed servers and the admin server sharing the same jmxremote port as 12345?

Comment: I got the answer. They can get different ports by setting -D values in Admin Console. And only by starting the servers in the admin console, those setting could be applied(do not run the script to start the server).

Comment: Correct - the -D values are only used when the server is started through the admin server (which is really using the nodemanager)

Comment: You actually don't need the "-Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder" parameter.  In my experience, this causes major performance issues in Weblogic and appears to provide no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Admin Console -> Servers -> Server-1 -> Server Start -> JVM Arguments

-DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8501 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.20.209

Admin Console -> Servers -> Server-2 -> Server Start -> JVM Arguments

-DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8502 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.20.209

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would improve the answer quite a lot if you could briefly explain what those options do and why they solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

along with below command line parameters ,

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port='you jmx port'
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder
```

Sometimes in the linux servers , imx connection doesn't get succeeded. that is because , in cloud linux host, in /etc/hosts so that the hostname resolves to the host address.

the best way to fix it is, ping the particular linux server from other machine in network and use that host IP address in the

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP address that obtained when you ping that linux server.
```

But never rely on the ipaddress that you get from linux server using ifconfig.me. the ip that you get there is masked one which is present in the host file.